# Constructor with Dependency Injection is causing http 500 error in react asp.net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, controller

The following controller handles use operations such as registering. However, when I make a call to the `Register` method in the controller using axios, I received the following error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

However, if I comment the code inside the constructor, the call is made successfully. I do not understand why the constructor is creating this problem. Any suggestions?

```
public class ApplicationUserController : ControllerBase
{
    private IUserService _userService;
    private IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public ApplicationUserController(
        IUserService userService,
        IMapper mapper,
        IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings
    )
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/ApplicationUser/Register")]
    public IActionResult Register([FromBody]ApplicationUserDto userDto)
    { 
         //implementation details
    }
}
```

Here is the IUSerServices interface:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    ApplicationUser Authenticate(string username, string password);

}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private myDbContext _context;

    public UserService(myDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public ApplicationUser Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        //implementation details
    }
}
```

The DI is registered in the `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
services.AddScoped<myDbContext>();
```

Comment: Have you registered your DB context with the DI as well, as your UserService is depending on the DbContext, so it will be constructing it when resolving the UserService.

Comment: @Jinish thanks for your reply! You mean adding `services.AddScoped<myDbContext>();` ? I just added and tried it. I still got the same error.

Comment: The way to register a dbcontext is a little different. Without having a look at the entire Startup class where all dependencies are registered its a guess work on what could be wrong. However, have a look at this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext]

Comment: @Jinish I followed the instructions here: https://hackernoon.com/asp-net-core-how-to-use-dependency-injection-in-entity-framework-core-4388fc5c148b. still the same error. I will keep working on it.

Comment: With these updates, now the problem is with `IMapper`. If I comment it, it works fine. I added `services.AddScoped<IMapper, Mapper>();` but still receiving the same error. Any ideas @Jinish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IMapper` is an interface from the AutoMapper library.

You need to add the package *`AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`* and call

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```